# Anagrams in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

Has anyone tried generating anagrams in scheme???

I have a list ( A B C D E F) and need to create anagrams of length 4. Like 'AAAA','ABCD','BCBC' etc.
I am totally confused. :(

Could someone please give me an heads-up on how I could go about it??

Comment: Do you have a anything that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... Recently I solved very similar task - create anagrams of length N from (0 1). Here is my solution. May be it helps you:

```
;; 
;; (define (generate n)) -> create list of string where
;;    * length of each string is n
;;    * each symbol of string is '0' or '1'
;;    * the list has all possible combinations of symbols '0' and '1'

(define (generate n)
(generate-engine (list "0" "1") n))

(define (generate-engine lst n)
 (cond
  [(= n 1) lst]
  [else (generate-engine (append (add-to-list lst "0") (add-to-list lst "1")) (- n 1))])    
)

(define (add-to-list lst symbol)
 (cond
  [(empty? lst) empty]
  [else (cons (add-to-element (first lst) symbol) (add-to-list (rest lst) symbol))]))

(define (add-to-element element symbol)
 (string-append element symbol)
)

;; example 

(generate 3)
```

Result:

```
(list "000" "100" "010" "110" "001" "101" "011" "111")
```

Comment: thank you :) i had completely lost my head on this!! half the issue was figuring out the syntax and errors :P

Comment: i understood how to go about it. copying will never help me get anywhere with scheme :P

Answer (score 0):

For each `i = 0..x` where `x` is the length of the anagram, generate a random number `r` such that `0 <= r <= n` where `n` is the number of elements in the list of letters. Now use `r` as an index into the list of letters and concatenate it to the result.

Answer (score 0):

#### Base case

Anagrams of length 1 are just the items in the list. Return the list.

#### Recursive case

Anagrams of length n are each of the items in the list appended to all of the anagrams of length `(- n 1)`.

From that you ought to be able to cook up some example of the base case and recursive case. You'll probably need a helper function.